# SVG line animation fading to background image?

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, background-image, fadeout

I have an SVG animation banner that I want to fade to a jpg image below it. The svg banner fades but the background image isn't same size, and it also fades, which I don't want.

I have made an svg line animation with a black bg that fades when the animation is done, but I want to reveal an image under or in place of the animation and black div when it's faded. I've tried everything I can find. I can get the image under it but it isn't the same size and location as the black div, and the image fades out also (I think due to the jquery fade div.center-div code?). I want the image to stay and I also want it responsive.
I made a jsfiddle, but the black div/svg doesn't fade in it though it does on my computer, not sure why.So you can't see the jpg under it here unfortunately -  https://jsfiddle.net/keltoid/dw2vcmoq/47/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
$("div.center-div").fadeOut(1200); {
$("div.center-div").remove(1200);
};
}, 4500);
});
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin:auto;
  
}
.wrapper {position:relative; background-image:url(https://filedn.com/lPKPli3Xz1KVxCemkqFzHfL/treebanner2.jpg) ;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index:3; 

  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 } 
  
.center-div
{
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index:1; 
  background-position: left top;           
}
.svg-container { 
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 100%; 
 vertical-align: middle; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 
}
.svg-content { 
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="center-div">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="893px"
 height="332.7px" viewBox="0 0 893 332.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 893 332.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="line">

 <path class="st1" d="M750.9,194.2c0.9,0.9,47.6-162.4,47.6-162.4l-34.8,0.6H55.2c0,0-13.9,0-13.7,13.7c0.1,8.7,0,248.6,0,248.6s-1.2,9.9,7.5,11.2s659.2,0.4,659.2,0.4s1.5,1.3,9.9-21.1c6.2-16.5,23.8-57.6,23.8-57.6l4.5-12.6c0,0,1.8-6.2,1.1-7"/>
<path class="st1" d="M739.8,232.8"/>

 <path class="st2" d="M739.8,232.8"/>

</g>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

The .center-div black bg and svg line work right and fade correctly. The background image shows once they fade but doesn't fill the space the black bg div did - it's smaller, it's not centered, and it fades also. I don't want that to fade. It also isn't responsive like the black div and line animation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the background disappears is that, once you remove the things inside it that take up space, it shrinks to nothing. By setting a width and height for it, the background remains after the fade.

The reason that the background image is not filling the rectangle is that you are not scaling it.

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/a8mu9z0v/

I used

```
background-size: cover;
```

But a different scaling method may work better for you.

**Edit:**

Making the background image responsive depends upon the directions that it should scale.

If you change the width of the wrapper in my example, but *leave the height as a fixed value*, it will scale the background image to fit the width but crop the bottom off the image when the scaled image exceeds the bounds.

```
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
```

If you change the background size to 100%, it will scale itself to the bounds of the wrapper, but it will not maintain its aspect ratio:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

If you want to maintain a certain aspect ratio for the wrapper, then there are certain css tricks that can help you do that, which you can see elsewhere.

Another option would be to use an image element instead of using a background image. Image elements intrinsically take up space. Your wrapper wouldn't shrink to nothing if it still had an image element inside it. It's easy to scale an image element up to the size of the window.

Comment: Thank you, that sort of works except for two things, I can change the width and height of the .wrapper - -- background image to take up the top of the page like a full banner --  but it isn't responsive.  My svg is, but the background image isn't. What can I do to make the background image responsive? As you saw, if I make the width 100% -- the image disappears.  I need it to stay.  Any ideas?

Comment: Edited in an attempt to answer that question.

Comment: Thank you but this still doesn't work - I tried putting an image in the wrapper div, that didn't work, are you saying use a css .element class?

Comment: Actually, I changed it from 'cover' to 'contain' and it seems to be working the way I want now...  I thought I'd tried that but.... seems to work, thank you for your help.

Comment: Can I ask another aspect of this? Can I add text to this SVG and have it fade in?

Comment: You can add text to an svg, but you may want to use a web font or convert the text to outlines so a missing font won't make it look wrong. CSS transitions do work on SVG elements.